# Scala TreeSet takeRight

Tags: scala, data-structures, treeset

I have a large set of integers that I'm using a TreeSet to store. My task is to find out the two numbers lesser than an input number.

For e.g Set(1, 5, 8, 9) and input = 6 should return (1, 5)
input = 8 should return (5, 8)

What i have so far in terms of code is the following:

```
treeSet.to(inputNumber).takeRight(2)
```

My understanding is that .to() returns a projection of the elements less that the input in logN time. I'm wondering what the complexity of the additional takeRight is. I cant figure out from docs.

I'm trying to make this as efficient as possible since my input list has millions of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier to look at the source code even before looking at docs.

In `TreeSet`:

```
override def takeRight(n: Int) = drop(size - math.max(n, 0))

override def drop(n: Int) = {
  if (n <= 0) this
  else if (n >= size) empty
  else newSet(RB.drop(tree, n))
}
```

In `RedBlackTree`:

```
def drop[A: Ordering, B](tree: Tree[A, B], n: Int): Tree[A, B] = blacken(doDrop(tree, n))
```

Deletion in the RBtree is `O(log n)`, so `takeRight` in Scala's `TreeSet`, which is backed by RBtree, is also `O(log n)`.